# Cannot Autowire Qualifier tagged RestTemplate from unit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired, resttemplate

I'm using an remote api in my web application. Some endpoints require an authentication header in the API I'm using. Because of this need I have created two different RestTemplateBuilder bean in my configuration class.

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @DependsOn(value = {"secureRestTemplateCustomizer"})
    @Qualifier("secureRestTemplateBuilder")
    public RestTemplateBuilder secureRestTemplateBuilder() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder(secureRestTemplateCustomizer());
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn(value = {"publicRestTemplateCustomizer"})
    @Qualifier("publicRestTemplateBuilder")
    public RestTemplateBuilder publicRestTemplateBuilder() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder(publicRestTemplateCustomizer());
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("secureRestTemplateCustomizer")
    public SecureRestTemplateCustomizer secureRestTemplateCustomizer() {
        return new SecureRestTemplateCustomizer();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("publicRestTemplateCustomizer")
    public PublicRestTemplateCustomizer publicRestTemplateCustomizer() {
        return new PublicRestTemplateCustomizer();
    }
}
```

And these are my custom `RestTemplateCustomizers`

```
@Component
public class SecureRestTemplateCustomizer implements RestTemplateCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler());
        restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new AuthorizationHeaderInterceptor());
    }
}
```

`PublicRestTemplateCustomizer`

```
@Component
public class PublicRestTemplateCustomizer implements RestTemplateCustomizer {
  @Override
  public void customize(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler());
  }
}
```

There is no problem when I want to use these `RestTemplateBuilder`s in my api clients like below. Spring can autowire them into my api client constructor.

```
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;
  @Autowired
  public LoginApiClient(@Qualifier("publicRestTemplateBuilder") RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
  }
```

But in my unit tests this usage is firing an error like

*Error creating bean with name 'loginApiClient' defined in file [..\LoginApiClient.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=publicRestTemplateBuilder)}*

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest({LoginApiClient.class})
@Category(IUnitTest.class)
public class LoginApiClientTest {

  @Autowired ILoginApiClient loginApiClient;

  @Autowired private MockRestServiceServer server;

  @Test
  public void validateToken_returns_true_for_valid_token() throws Exception{
    String token = "token";

    this.server.expect(requestTo(this.validateTokenUrl))
               .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
               .andRespond(withSuccess(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(validTokenResponse(token)), MediaType
                       .APPLICATION_JSON));

    Boolean isValid = loginApiClient.validateToken(token);

    server.verify();
    assertThat(isValid,is(equalTo(true)));
  }

}
```

How can I mock these RestTemplates truly and use in my unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the `@ComponentScan(value = "your.package")` in your `Main` application class

Answer (score 0):

You do not have context specified.

Try adding this annotation to uour test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes=RestTemplateConfiguration.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
```

See this article for details: [spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles) - it's for Spring 3, but newer versions of Spring work similarly.

Here's a newer tutorial: [junit-spring-integration-example](https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-spring-integration-example/)